# Running a PHP script completely on server side

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm having a problem where putty gets regularly disconnected. So, when I run a PHP script from the terminal, it always gets interrupted. The script is supposed to run several hours, so I'm not having any luck with it.

How can I completely run this from the server side? I'm reading about cron jobs, but I'm having a hard time understanding at this time. Is there any alternative to cron for what I need?

I have several script PHP files that need to be run, one by one, or perhaps two at a time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to leave it run in a cron job - you can just run the php script inside a screen.

Simply type;

```
screen php /path/to/myphpscript.php
```

A screen will continue running even after you disconnect from PuTTY. If you need to check up on it, you can use;

```
screen -r
```

To re-attach yourself to this process, and view any output.

Comment: This works well. I did: 1: `screen` to get in a screen. 2: `php my_scripy.php` to run the script. 3: from this point on, I can connect or detach from the screen and the script continues until it's finished.

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the process from terminating when the session disconnects.

Something like this would work:

`nohup php myscript.php`

Comment: Mahmoud, I trying this right now. After I run this command, close putty, and reconnect, I don't see the process when I type `ps a`. Is that normal?

Comment: `ps a` only shows the current session's processes. Look at top.

Comment: This works as well. Thank you! Is there a way to know if the previous session's process is still running in a new session?

Comment: I think `ps a` shows a screen's process in any session. This will works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cron job to start the php script periodically based on a list of time tasks. [More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). You could also start the task in the background from the console. i.e. `php-cgi script.php&` this would make the script a background task

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/); it allows you to detach and reattach a session later, which is perfect for long-running scripts. Cron is a good option if you want it to happen in a recurring fashion; one-off batch jobs can be scheduled with something like [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29). For more intense computing needs, you might want to look into a more full-fledged job scheduling system like [TORQUE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TORQUE_Resource_Manager).

Answer (score 0):

You can run your program in background

```
php ./yourscript.php &
```

Comment: Backgrounding a process does not allow it to survive a session termination.