# How do I execute a php file on the server using the screen command?

Tags: php, server, background-process, gnu-screen

I was looking at this post which is where I got the idea to use screens to execute my php scripts on the server:
[Running a PHP script completely on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200178/running-a-php-script-completely-on-server-side)

I was successfully able to execute a php script using:

`screen`

`php ./file.php`

However, this did not work for me:

`screen ./file.php`

And it was that last way of doing it that was recommended in that post I linked.

All it says is: `Cannot exec './file.php': Permission Denied`

`sudo screen ./file.php` did not work either.

Comment: sudo screen php ./file.php

Comment: Don't `sudo` unless you really need to (which you don't since it worked without `sudo` in the two step approach at the start of the question).

Comment: @Quentin I believe you, but may I ask why?

Comment: Giving code superuser access to the system when it doesn't need it does nothing except increase the severity of any security issues that might be in that code.

Comment: @KacyRaye - don't grant additional privileges as per sudo unless you actually need them, it's not good security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `screen` a shell command that works.

You had a shell command that works in your first attempt.

You then removed part of it when you tried to pass it to `screen`. Don't do that. Leave the command intact.

```
screen php ./file.php
```

If you want the PHP script to be executable *directly* (i.e. without passing it as an argument to the `php` command line binary) then you need to:

- Make sure that the first line explains how to execute it (`#!/usr/bin/env php`)
- Set the permissions on it so it is executable (`chmod u+x file.php`)

Comment: But I was first! :D, with that comment

Comment: @Quentin Cool thank you.  Super clear. I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.  I guess that post I linked just assumed the php file was already set to be an executable.